# Parallel processing of Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: rest, powershell

What is the best way to parallel process `Invoke-RestMethod`?

I'm trying to retrieve a list of coin prices, currently I'm using a `foreach` loop to retrieve the price. Doing this with 30 odd coins takes a while:

```
$coins = @("XRP", "TRX", "VEN", "CND", "ICX", "XLM", "BNB")
$base = "ETH"

while ($true) {
    foreach ($coin in $coins) {
        $pair = $coin + $base
        $uri = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=$pair"
        $price = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI $uri |
                 select Price -ExpandProperty Price
        Write-Host $price    
    }
}
```

Comment: Also - why the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base url returns all the prices... so instead of filtering it in a loop, you can grab them all and parse them as a PSObject

```
$uri    = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price"
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -URI $uri 
$prices = $request.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$prices | Where-Object symbol -IN "XRPETH", "TRXETH", "VENETH", "CNDETH", "ICXETH", "XLMETH", "BNBETH"
```

Comment: P.S. the `Invoke-RestMethod` basically does the JSON conversion for you, if you're that way inclined. `/shrug`

Comment: ahhhh thank you so much dude! never thought of doing it that way...!

Comment: @Tommy please also mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you!

Comment: all done thank you again!